# React not mapping certain objects in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to dynamically render an input form, based on the selection of a radio button. I have an array that is incremented every time the user select an radio button.
The problem is: I append an object to the array, and try to map that array on render() function. The map apparently is ignoring the object that I insert.

The select radio button code:

```js
<MDBInput
    onClick={() => {
        let dependentFullName = dependent.dependentFullName;
        let dependentAnswerList = this.state[dependentFullName];
        let newQuestionData = {
            question: thing.pergunta,
            answer: true,
            answerRaised: true,
            info: ''
        };

        dependentAnswerList[thing.pergunta] = newQuestionData;
        this.setState({
            [dependentFullName]: dependentAnswerList
        })
    }}

    checked={this.state[dependent.dependentFullName][thing.pergunta] ? this.state[dependent.dependentFullName][thing.pergunta]["answer"] ? true : false : false}
    label='Sim'
    type='radio'
    id={"holder." + thing.pergunta}
/>
```

The map rendering code prototype:

```js
{this.state.holder.map((question) => (<React.Fragment>
<h5>{question}</h5> <h5>{question.question}</h5></React.Fragment>))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a state with a **new reference** of your mutated array:

```
this.setState({
  [dependentFullName]: [...dependentAnswerList]
});
```

On state change, react makes **shallow comparison** with the previous one, in your case it has the same reference, therefore no render triggered.

[What does setState do?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-does-setstate-do).

> `setState()` schedules an update to a component’s state object. **When state changes, the component responds by re-rendering**.

From [`setState` API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> Both state and props received by the updater function are guaranteed to be up-to-date. The output of the updater is shallowly merged with the state.

A possible full-fix may look like:

```
const onClick = () => {
  const dependentFullName = dependent.dependentFullName;
  const dependentAnswerList = this.state[dependentFullName];
  const newQuestionData = {
    question: thing.pergunta,
    answer: true,
    answerRaised: true,
    info: ''
  };
  this.setState({
    [dependentFullName]: {
      ...dependentAnswerList,
      [thing.pergunta]: newQuestionData
    }
  });
};
<MDBInput onClick={onClick} {...rest}/>;
```